# Cycle Backface culling didn't work

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I will put some screenshot to demonstrate the problem

The backface culling didn't work I put on the option in the menu I have create the material, everything work when I am in the material viewport but when I hit Shift+Z and when I do the render the backface cull don't work

Have I forgot somehing ?[image][image]enter image description here
[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do.why do you need backculling in the first place? Are you trying to use an image as texture like in the OpenGL texture shading view?

Answer (score 1):

**In Blender 2.79:**
For your backface cull object, go to Object settings and at least disable shadow:
[image: Object properties settings]

This material node setup is all you need for pure black:
[image: Material Node setup]

Both shift-Z and F12 render work:
[image]

**In Blender 2.80 (as of February 27, 2019):**
Use the same material node setup as shown above for 2.79. Then go to Material tab and change Blend Mode to Alpha Clip (or something similar):
[image]

Cheers!